# Trouble looping through an array and spitting out API results

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, variables

I'm using the NY state legislature API and running into trouble where I'm getting the same output for each item (related only to the first item in the array). I checked and the counter does seem to be increasing, so I'm not sure then why it's not displaying ALL the bill numbers.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        const bills = ["A6143", "S737", "A2260", "S8455A", "A559", "S737", "A3041", "S1234"];
        var printNo = [];
        var title = [];
        var counter = 0;
        bills.forEach(function (item, index) {
            $.getJSON("https://legislation.nysenate.gov/api/3/bills/2021/" + bills[counter] + "?key=[mykeygoeshere]", function(item) {
                printNo[counter] = item.result.printNo;
                title[counter] = item.result.title;
                document.write("<p>" + printNo[counter] + ". ");
                document.write(title[counter] + "</p>");
                counter++;
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Where I'm trying to eventually get with this is to compare the latest items for ALL bills and display a feed of the most recent updates. (So the two most recent actions might be the same bill, for example.) But first, I can't even figure out how to iterate and display titles in an array, let alone the complicated "actions" stuff.

Here's the API info, but I don't think it's relevant here. Just in case: https://legislation.nysenate.gov/static/docs/html/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `document.write` after the page loads. It completely wipes out the whole page. Since $.getJSON is asynchronous each set of `document.write` will likely wipe out previous ones also

Instead create elements and insert into the document, in a container you have already established to hold them.

Next you can map all these requests to an array of promises and use Promise.all() to process all the results after all the requests have resolved

Something along the lines of:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  const apiUrl = "https://legislation.nysenate.gov/api/3/bills/2021/";
  const bills = ["A6143", "S737", "A2260", "S8455A", "A559", "S737", "A3041", "S1234"];
  // array of request promises
  const requests = bills.map(bill => {
    return $.getJSON(apiUrl + bill + "?key=[mykeygoeshere]")
  });

  Promise.all(requests).then(results => {
    for (let {printNo, title} of results) {
      const $p = $('<p>').text(printNo + '.' + title);                  
      $('#someContainerId').append($p)
    }   
  }).catch(err => console.log('Oooops, one of the requests failed'));
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful. I'm trying to figure out how to make printNo and title not be undefined with your example, since I can no longer just do item.result.printNo. I see the part where it says "let {printNo, title} of results" but don't really understand what that line means? It's in a for loop. Maybe I'm supposed to define those variables in the array of return promises after line 6?

Comment: It is a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Comment: Thanks again. I added "console.log(results);" and was able to see that it IS in fact already grabbing the elements I thought it wasn't. The reason it's undefined must be something unrelated. So while I still haven't figured out how to get to where I want to go, this is resolved since I can see the data in the console!

Answer (score 2):

You are updating your counter in the callback from the jquery getJson call. So each iteration of the forEach has the same value of counter.

Increment the counter in the body of the forEach function, at the same level as getJSON.

Why are you even bothering with bills[counter] on the url? You get each item  in the argument to the forEach callback function.

```
$.getJSON("https://legislation.nysenate.gov/api/3/bills/2021/" + item...
```